# How can I attach an image in a form and send it as payload to the backend in Angular/TypeScript?

Tags: html, angular, user-interface, typescript-typings

I want to attach an image in the form and then send it as payload at the backend to save it in the database. How should I proceed with Angular/TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using PrimeFaces UI components for Angular and there is a specific upload directive available that works for us.

app.component.html

```
<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" [customUpload]="true" (uploadHandler)="myUploader($event)"></p-fileUpload>
```

app.component.ts

```
myUploader(event) {
    //event.files == files to upload
}
```

More can be found [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/fileupload)